# Use scipy.optimize.least_squares to fit Gaussian Mixture Model to spectral data

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, gaussian, minimization, mixture-model

I'm trying to fit the sum of 3 Gaussians to experimental data using `scipy.minimize` function.

I need your help in properly passing the objective function since that is where error seems to be pointing to. Obviously, I'm new to Python.

The documentation for `scipy.minimize` does not have clear examples for this case and the questions about GMMs asked here previously were poorly formulated.
Please advise...

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen_der, rosen_hess

x = numpy.arange(0, 55)
y = [-0.00058032, -0.00063992, -0.00057869, -0.00058395, -0.00053528,  -0.0002694, -0.0003716, -0.000284,    0.00104651,  0.00209935,  0.00360213,  0.00502779,  0.00625538,  0.00715873,   0.00753231,  0.00712235,  0.00689089,  0.0061677,  0.00544124,  0.00478251,  0.00487787,  0.00415067,  0.00368579,  0.00370327,  0.00323007,  0.0029862,   0.00250529,  0.00219493,  0.00212242,  0.00209026,  0.0020827,  0.00204044,  0.00218628,  0.00236552,  0.00245056,  0.00282404,  0.0031072,   0.00332862,  0.00351655,  0.00367349,  0.00387923,  0.00395812,  0.00388796,  0.00379902,  0.00369458,  0.00350222,  0.00337815,  0.0032241,  0.00306897,  0.00294152,  0.00276761,  0.00257586,  0.00231613,  0.00211727,  0.00190347]

# experimental data: y
# objective function that is to be minimized: G1 + G2 + G3 - y
def sumGauss(x, y, *args):
    m1, m2, m3, s1, s2, s3, k1, k2, k3 = args
    ret = -y
    ret += k1 * numpy.exp(-(x - m1)**2 / (2 * s1**2))
    ret += k2 * numpy.exp(-(x - m2)**2 / (2 * s2**2))
    ret += k3 * numpy.exp(-(x - m3)**2 / (2 * s3**2))
    return ret

initial_values = [15, 29, 43, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

res = minimize(sumGauss(x, y), initial_values, method='trust-exact',
                jac=rosen_der, hess=rosen_hess,
                options={'gtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fit_gaussian.py", line 64, in <module>    res = minimize(sumGauss(x, y), params, method='trust-exact',
File "fit_gaussian.py", line 41, in sumGauss
m1, m2, m3, s1, s2, s3, k1, k2, k3 = args
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 9, got 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just a few things to change. If you want to fit data it is better to use `least_squares`:

`from scipy.optimize import least_squares`

Make `y` a numpy array, so you can perform arithmetic operations on it:

`y=numpy.array(y)`

Do not unpack `args`, they should remain a single input. Optimisation functions usually work on the 1st input argument, so move it forward:

```
def sumGauss(args, x, y):
    m1, m2, m3, s1, s2, s3, k1, k2, k3 = args
    ret = -y
    ret += k1 * np.exp(-(x - m1)**2 / (2 * s1**2))
    ret += k2 * np.exp(-(x - m2)**2 / (2 * s2**2))
    ret += k3 * np.exp(-(x - m3)**2 / (2 * s3**2))
    return ret
```

Then run the optimisation, those jacobians are for different functions so don't use them. Pass the extra params your functions needs as a tuple with keyword `args`:

`res = least_squares(sumGauss, initial_values, method='trf', args=(x,y))`

Your optimised args:
`res.x`

Plot, `res.fun` are the residuals:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(y,'o');plt.plot(res.fun+y);plt.plot(res.fun)
```